# How can I reference a column without entering the column name?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have several tables with many columns that am supposed to insert data. I dont' want to retype the name of the columns again as I've already typed them in the "SQLAlchemy Class Defination".

From other questions posted, I see you can get the name of the columns with the code below.

```
for c in datatable.__table__.columns.keys():
    print(c)
```

This will give out the column names. However, what I want is to insert data into the column not just read the column name. Below is what I've tried out.

```
for_counter = 0
for instance in SESSION.query(SampleClass).filter(SampleClass.id == 2): 
    instance.__table__.columns.keys()[(for_counter)] = "texttoinsert"
    for_counter += 1
```

I thought I could "index" the column with this but when the code runs and I check the database, only the auto increment "ID" column and the dates that are set to default to "now" get data. All the other columns in the "instance" don't get any data while I expected to find "texttoinsert" in the columns.

Basically I want to build just one function that will "maybe use" column index to insert the data as long as I've specified the name of the table. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop is replacing the values in the `instance.__table__.columns.keys()` array instead of setting the corresponding attribute on `instance`. This should do the trick:

```
for instance in SESSION.query(SampleClass).filter(SampleClass.id == 2): 
  for colname in instance.__table__.columns.keys():
    setattr(instance, colname, 'text_to_insert')
```

As a side note, since all your instances have the same keys, inverting the two loops would lead to better performance (you don't need to recreate the keys array every time).

Comment: This has worked. dude, you just saved me tons of hair pulling typing. Importantly also, I have reversed the loops and from taking 4 seconds it is now taking 0.514 seconds! Thanks for the extra hint